# Laravel ORM query builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

I have the following interrogation that I want to translate into Laravel's Query Builder:

```
SELECT t.name, t.description, u.first_name as assignee_fname, u.last_name as assignee_lname, 
us.first_name as reporter_fname, us.last_name as reporter_lname
FROM `tasks` AS t
LEFT JOIN `users` AS u 
ON (t.asignee_id = u.id)
LEFT JOIN `users` AS us
ON (t.reporter_id = us.id);
```

Do you have any idea how can I do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DB::table('tasks')->select('tasks.name', 'users.first_name AS assignee_fname', ...) //and the rest of your column
->leftJoin('users', 'taks.asignee_id', '=', 'users.id')
->leftJoin('users', 'tasks.reporter_id', '=', 'users.id')
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Can I use aliases for the user table as I used in the question? 
It is important due to the fact that I have to get information for two different persons from the same table.